# How many numbers are required to describe attitude or orientation in $n$-dimensions?

Tags: spacetime, group-theory, rotation, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

In general, the attitude or orientation of a rigid object is described by three numbers. For an aircraft, these might be the *pitch*, *roll*, and *yaw* with respect to the direction of motion. For a spacecraft, these might be three angles with respect to an inertial frame of reference such as the the ecliptic plane and Earth's position at the March equinox.

Attitude in three dimensions requires three numbers to define it. But the equivalent in two dimensions (a plane) requires only a single number.  In one dimension, 'attitude' has no meaning and requires zero numbers to define it.

So how do I continue the following table?

| number of dimensions | numbers required to describe attitude |
| --- | --- |
| 1-dimension | 0 |
| 2-dimensions | 1 |
| 3-dimensions | 3 |
| 4-dimensions | ? |
| n-dimensions | ? |

[ Does the term 'attitude' have any meaning in the four dimensions of spacetime? ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ZeroTheHero says, $n(n-1)/2$.

Take an n dimensional cube in n dimensional space oriented aligned with an X, Y, Z, ... coordinate system. How do we give it an arbitrary new orientation?

Give the X edge an arbitrary orientation. There are n degrees of freedom. You can specify its new direction as a vector by specifying n numbers.

Give the Y edge an arbitrary orientation subject to the constraint that it must stay perpendicular to the X edge. There are $n - 1$ degrees of freedom, and thus $n - 1$ numbers are needed.

Continue through all the edges, and you get the result.

Comment: I can understand this answer. So it's n-1 to direct the first edge, n-2 to direct the second edge, n-3 for the 3rd edge etc.  The sum from n to 1 of (n-1) = n(n-1)/2

Answer (score 7):

This would be the number of parameters needed to specify an element in the group $SO(n)$, and this number is $n(n-1)/2$.  Thus:

- $n=2$ requires one parameter
- $n=3$ requires $3$ real parameters,
- $n=4$ requires $6$,
- $n=5$ requires $10$ etc.

Comment: You answered the question, but are there more details you can add? How is this number derived, who derived it, and under what motivation? To me, $n(n-1)/2$ is the number of elements in the upper triangular area of a $n×n$ matrix.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Which makes sense because the $SO(n)$ generators are antisymmetric $n\times n$ matrices. The elements on the diagonal are zero, and the elements in the triangular area below the diagonal are the negatives of those above.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou If you represent the orientation as an $n \times n$ orthogonal rotation matrix $R$, the orthogonality condition is $R^TR = I$. Since $R^TR$ is symmetric, this gives $n(n+1)/2$ equations that must be satisfied by the $n^2$ elements of R. So the number of independent parameters that can be chosen for an arbitrary matrix $R$ is $n^2 - n(n+1)/2 = n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: ... just to expand on what might be the "non-obvious" step in the previous comment, if you write out the expression for each element of $R^TR$ you have an equation setting that expression either to $0$ for the off-diagonal terms, or $1$ for the diagonal terms. But since $R^TR$ is symmetric, each pair of off-diagonal terms gives the same equation, so the total number of equations is $n(n+1)/2$ not $n^2$.

Comment: Yes.  The algebra $so(n)$ is spanned by the real antisymmetric matrices, and there are $n(n-1)/2$ of those; there will be one parameter for each generator as the group element is obtained by exponentiating the generators.